# How can I see my uploaded images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Ruby version 2.2.4
Rails version 5.0.0.1
Carrierwave

Hello people

I am a totally beginner in RoR and after long hours I finally uploaded an picture from my android app to ruby on rails. I have the code from a tutorial which provides the upload function. However the function how you can see the picture is missed. How can I implement this in ruby on rails? I want to see the pictures in a table

Here is what I have so far

[image]

And here is the code: views/items/inde.html.erb

```
h1>Rails-API-Fileupload-tutorial-Cariierwave-Single</h1>
<h2>Listing documents</h2>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Filename</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.id %></td>
        <td><%= item%></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :items, :pictues

  root to: redirect('/items')

  post  to: 'items'
end
```

UPDATE: Hello People, thanks for your fast help. When I use `<%= image_tag item.picture %>` I get this
[image]

Are there some other ideas?

UPDATE: I think I cannot see the pictures because I have a routing problem. When I right click on a picture and want to open in new browser I get

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET]
```

What can I do to fix this?

UPDATE: My Uploadfolder is outside of Ruby and Rails folder. Should it be in the public ordner instead?

Answer (score 1):

`<td><%= item%></td>`

should be something like :

### edit sorry I forgot the image tag...

`<td><%= image_tag item.picture %></td>`

Comment: If I do this I only see the local adress of the file: #<Item:0x44e11d8> C%3A/Users/Clemens/Desktop/Filme/Upload%20Images/item/picture/23/IMG_20160911_232804.jpg . But I want to see the image in the browser. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To display the image, use an `image_tag`.

```
<%= image_tag item.picture_url %>
```

Comment: Thank you but if I do this, I see not the picture, only an image of the picture file

Comment: @Peter, you said you're using Carrierwave right? Let me know if my updated solution works.

Comment: Yes exactly, I juse CarrierWave. Too bad, this also shows me not the picture. Maybe my picture captured and uploaded from my s7 handy is too big? (1> mb)

Comment: @Peter That has nothing to do with this. Maybe reading the carrierwave documentation will help you.https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Comment: I think the problem is based on an routing error. When I right click on an image I get this:  ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET]  Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: And my uploadfolder is outside of Ruby and Rails on the desktop. Should it be in the public ordner in Ruby on Rails instead?